# BigTreeTech SKR 1.3 (LPC1768), mbed examples not working

Tags: nxp, lpc1768

I have a Chinese LPC1768-based board I used to control with [Marlin](https://marlinfw.org/) firmware, and recently I started to want to program it my own way instead.

So, I was successful with PlatformIO and Marlin's custom library they have extracted (Arduino-like): https://github.com/p3p/pio-nxplpc-arduino-lpc176x. I am able to blink whatever pin I want.

But, when I try to move to standard Mbed OS/baremetal examples e.g. https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-blinky-baremetal and compile it either via PlatformIO or the online compiler, uploaded firmware does not function. I am sure the bootloader writes the binary to the flash memory, but nothing happens, no signs of life.

So, the question is: am I wrong supposing that any LPC1768-based chip is the same as a chip-based development board? Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: the chip might be the same, but the external oscillator, power supply, pins connected to LEDs, … might be totally different.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for new ideas! Pins are OK, I checked the data sheet and got them working on the Arduino-like framework. But I cannot notice the real difference between compiler/linker parameters in https://github.com/platformio/platform-nxplpc and https://github.com/p3p/pio-nxplpc-arduino-lpc176x with my not-yet-trained eye.